# How to solve this logarithmic equation with sum of exponential functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, quadratics

I come across this logarithmic equation recently (solve for $x \in \mathbb{R}$) :
$$ 2x \geq \log_2 \left( \frac{35}{3} \cdot 6^{x-1} - 2 \cdot 9^{x - \frac{1}{2}} \right)$$
With few quick changes, this equation can be rewritten as :
$$ \ln \left( \frac{4}{3} \right) x + \ln 3 \geq \ln \left(\frac{35}{6} \cdot 2^x - 2 \cdot 3^x \right)$$
So, how do you handle the right part ? Factoring doesn't appear to be so trivial...

Comment: Have you tried raising both sides to the power of $2$?

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks.

Comment: These are not equations, they are inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

We need to solve $$2^{2x}\geq\frac{35}{18}\cdot6^x-\frac{2}{3}\cdot9^x,$$ where $$ \frac{35}{18}\cdot6^x-\frac{2}{3}\cdot9^x>0$$ and after substitution $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x=t$ we obtain a quadratic inequality:
$$\frac{2}{3}t^2-\frac{35}{18}t+1\geq0.$$
Can you end it now?

I got the following answer.
$$(-\infty,-1]\cup\left[2,\log_{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{35}{12}\right).$$

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the substitution trick, I couldn't find this one. Thanks!